# Get threaded results for associated model in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, associations

I have 2 database-tables which are connected as followed:

```
ProjectProduct hasMany Bde
Bde belongsTo ParentBde / Bde hasMany ChildBde
```

The first association is new and shall be added into the application now. Since then I used `$this->Bde->find('threaded')` to get an threaded array of these records.

Now I need/want to query the ProjectProduct-table and wanted to use the containable-behavior to get all associated Bdes.

Now I'm wondering: Is it possible (in a Cake way) to still get threaded results with a call of find on `ProjectProduct`?
I tried doing `$this->ProjectProduct->find('threaded', array('contain' => 'Bde'))` but this will try to get threaded results on `ProjectProduct`.

I'm expecting an array like this:

```
Array (
    [ProjectProduct] => Array (
        [id] => 17,
        [Bde] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [id] => 1,
                [project_product_id] => 17,
                [children] => Array()
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find any information how this can be done in one call or the "Cakish" way, I've done it like this:

```
$project_products = $this->Project->ProjectProduct->find('all');
    foreach ($project_products as $key => $project_product) {
        $project_products[$key]['Bde'] = $this->Project->Bde->find('threaded', array('conditions' => array('Bde.project_product_id' => $project_product['ProjectProduct']['id'])));
    }
```

If someone has a better way in doing this I really appreciate any other ideas!